# php - file_get_contents missing html tags

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting script from some url like this

```
 $dom = new DomDocument();
 $url = "http://www.example.com";
 @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url); 
 foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
 if ($element->tagName == 'script' && strpos($element->getAttribute('src'), '.js') == true)
{
    $files = $element->getAttribute('src');  
    $link[]=$files;


}


}
$domc = new DomDocument();
foreach($link as $ln ){
$html = file_get_contents($ln);
$script = $html;
print_r ($script);
}
```

Everything is working as expected, but if I have inside script append function I am missing everything inside quotes. For example this:

```
  $(".divc").append("<div></div>")
```

gives me in php output

```
 $(".divc").append("")
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `<div></div>` are considered as html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try viewing the source. Are the  tags in there? If so, you either need to escape the HTML characters or you need to change the output format of your PHP document by adding this at the very top:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```